# Intermittent Cordova iOS build failure with Visual Studio 2015 RTM Cordova Tools

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 RTM to build an Ionic project through a remote (but local) mac. It works fine with a blank project, but now my builds are failing with this error:

> 0B07C065:x509 certificate routines:X509_STORE_add_cert:cert already in hash table:openssl\crypto\x509\x509_lu.c:346

After this error any following builds will fail immediately, without further explanation. This is caused by the \plugins\remote_ios.json file becoming corrupted. Deleting or fixing the file will allow builds to be attempted again, sometimes successfully, sometimes repeating the same pattern.

I reproduced from a new project, and found it occured after installing the Globalization plugin, but since then I've managed to install it fine, so that may just be a false indicator.

I've tried:

- Cleaning and rebuilding
- Clearing the cordova cache
- Reinstalling vs-tac
- Upgrading node on both machines
- Upgrading cordova on both machines

Nothing seems to work consistently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for using VS 2015. This is an intermittent issue caused due to a race condition in [nodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16187178/nodejs-v0-10-x-freebsd-x509-store-add-certcert-already-in-hash-table/28314646) and has an open [jira](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/712) for io.js. This is planned to be merged in future versions of NodeJS.

While we investigate a fix for this issue within our tools, is it possible for you to run your remote agent in a non-secure mode, by running `remotebuild --secure false`

Thanks once again for using VS 2015 Tools for Apache Cordova.

Comment: Running remotebuild in non-secure mode has allowed me to build without errors so far.